# How to use RegEx in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to transfer the following code from Python to Java, but I get an error, while doing it:

```py
import re

payload = re.search(
    r'decrypt\.setPrivateKey\("(?P<privateKey>[^"]+)".*?'
    r'decrypt\.decrypt\("(?P<cryptText>[^"]+)".*?'
    r'document\.cookie="ipp_uid=(?P<ipp_uid>[^"]+)".*?'
    r'document\.cookie="ipp_uid1=(?P<ipp_uid1>[^"]+)".*?'
    r'document\.cookie="ipp_uid2=(?P<ipp_uid2>[^"]+)".*?'
    r'url\s\+=\s"(?P<makeURL>.*?)"\;.*?'
    r'salt="(?P<salt>[^"]+)"',
    ret.content.decode('utf-8'),
    re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL
)
```

I have already tried the following code:

```
String patternString = "decrypt\\.setPrivateKey\\(\"(?P<privateKey>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                    + "    decrypt\\.decrypt\\(\"(?P<cryptText>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                    + "    document\\.cookie=\"ipp_uid=(?P<ipp_uid>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                    + "    document\\.cookie=\"ipp_uid1=(?P<ipp_uid1>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                    + "    document\\.cookie=\"ipp_uid2=(?P<ipp_uid2>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                    + "    url\\s\\+=\\s\"(?P<makeURL>.*?)\"\\;.*?\n"
                    + "    salt=\"(?P<salt>[^\"]+)\"";
            Pattern payload = Pattern.compile(patternString);
            String content = new String(html.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
            Matcher m = payload.matcher(html);
            if(m.find()){
                System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(0));
            }else{
                System.out.println("not found");
            }
```

... but I am getting this error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 27
decrypt\.setPrivateKey\("(?P<privateKey>[^"]+)".*?
    decrypt\.decrypt\("(?P<cryptText>[^"]+)".*?
    document\.cookie="ipp_uid=(?P<ipp_uid>[^"]+)".*?
    document\.cookie="ipp_uid1=(?P<ipp_uid1>[^"]+)".*?
    document\.cookie="ipp_uid2=(?P<ipp_uid2>[^"]+)".*?
    url\s\+=\s"(?P<makeURL>.*?)"\;.*?
    salt="(?P<salt>[^"]+)"
                             ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1957)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2896)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2053)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1998)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1698)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at fabian.site.MyModule.test(MyModule.java:76)
    at fabian.site.MyModule.run(MyModule.java:61)
    at fabian.thread.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:50)
```

Thank you for your help guys!!

Comment: I guess it's complaining about the `'` chars, and since there is no "raw string" (i.e., `r'...'`) in Java you should remove them all.

Comment: Yeah the `r` looks to be an identifier in PHP, not part of the regex.

Comment: Also if `html` is already of type String then `String content = new String(html.getBytes(), "UTF-8");` is completely unneeded.  Just search `html` directly.

Comment: Please don't post long code segments in comments.  The result is completely unreadable and unformatted.  Please edit your question and post the code properly formatted into the question.

Comment: excuse me, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Two things stand out to me:

- Named capturing groups in Java are structured like `(?<name>X)`, not `(?P<name>X)`, so you should remove the Ps
- The names cannot contain "_", so you should replace `ipp_uid` with something like `ippUid` (only letters and numbers)

```
String patternString = "decrypt\\.setPrivateKey\\(\"(?<privateKey>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                + "    decrypt\\.decrypt\\(\"(?<cryptText>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                + "    document\\.cookie=\"ipp_uid=(?<ippuid>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                + "    document\\.cookie=\"ipp_uid1=(?<ippuid1>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                + "    document\\.cookie=\"ipp_uid2=(?<ippuid2>[^\"]+)\".*?\n"
                + "    url\\s\\+=\\s\"(?<makeURL>.*?)\"\\;.*?\n"
                + "    salt=\"(?<salt>[^\"]+)\"";
```

I don't have any sample data, so it's hard to tell whether it works this way, but it does compile without errors.

Comment: thank you now it says not found, but why? here is a picture of the names: http://prntscr.com/orr7j8